# Quando si deve togliere il "che" di "pensare che", "credere che", "ammettere che", ecc?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Frequentemente ho letto frasi che hanno le strutture “pensare che”, “credere che”, “ammettere che”, ecc. ***senza la congiunzione "che"***. Ecco alcuni esempi tratti da Internet:

> - Penso sia necessario un chiarimento tra l’allenatore e la società.
> - *Chiara Luna* è un romanzo ambientato in Inghilterra nel 1880 ed ho voluto misurarmi con una storia ambientata in un contesto storico ben preciso ed è una cosa che credo non farò mai più.
> - Il tempo invece del tunnel è di circa 20 minuti che devo ammettere passano in fretta e senza problemi di pressione o altro.

Non riesco a capire però quando si debba togliere la congiunzione "che" da tali espressioni. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Nella seconda frase “ed” dovrebbe essere sostituita con due punti (o punto e virgola, a scelta); nella terza frase “devo ammettere” dovrebbe essere tra virgole. Anche “del tunnel” mi lascia perplesso, preferirei “nel tunnel”.

Comment: Nella seconda e terza frase "che" ha il ruolo di pronome relativo, non di congiunzione. Come già risposto, il "che" si può omettere se è congiunzione (non se è pronome relativo) e il verbo della subordinata è al congiuntivo, al condizionale o al futuro.

Comment: @karoshi: Perché il "che" nelle espressioni "credo ***che*** non farò mai più", "devo ammettere ***che*** passano in fretta" sarebbe un pronome relativo? Io penso che sia una congiunzione.

Comment: @charo nelle frasi scritte così "che" è effettivamente una congiunzione. Ma gli esempi che hai citato nella domanda originale sono diversi: "*è una cosa* che credo non farò ..." ("che" == "una cosa", complemento oggetto, pronome relativo). "20 minuti che, devo ammettere, passano in fretta" (ho aggiunto le virgole per chiarezza). Anche qui, "che" == "20 minuti" (soggetto), quindi è ancora pronome relativo.

Comment: @karoshi:Nella domanda ho scritto di aver letto frasi con le strutture “pensare che”, “credere che”, “ammettere che”, ecc ***senza il "che"***. Dunque, i miei esempi avevano la congiunzione "che" omessa.

Comment: L'unico caso dubbio è il secondo, che potrebbe anche scriversi come "una cosa che credo che non farò ...". Il secondo "che" è una congiunzione e quindi, siccome il verbo è al futuro, si può omettere (come fa l'autore). Il primo "che" è pronome relativo e non si può togliere. Forse non avevo capito bene a cosa ti riferivi, spero adesso sia più chiaro.

Comment: @egreg: Ecco i siti web da dove ho tratto queste frasi: http://www.intercom.publinet.it/ic14/intervistagotico.htm, http://www.regarderadroite.com/london-escape/.

Comment: @karoshi: Pensi che la domanda non sia chiara e forse si dovrebbe riscrivere in altro modo?

Comment: @charo no, è ben scritta, sono io che non avevo capito bene. Scrivo una risposta che spero sarà un po' più chiara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una regola approssimativa: *solo con certi verbi* della frase principale, se il "che" è congiunzione, e il verbo nella subordinata è al congiuntivo o al condizionale, il "che" si può omettere. In certi casi funziona anche col futuro indicativo, specialmente se il verbo della subordinata è negato.

> Penso che sia stato Marco -> Penso sia stato Marco.
>
> Suppongo che sarebbe stato meglio venire in treno -> Suppongo sarebbe stato meglio venire in treno.
>
> Spero che verrai -> Spero verrai.
>
> Non credo che andrò al cinema domani -> Non credo andrò al cinema domani.

Però non sempre funziona col futuro:

> Penso che domani studierò -> *Penso domani studierò (o quantomeno, credo che nessuno lo direbbe)

I verbi della frase principale con i quali è possibile l'omissione del "che" congiunzione alle condizioni sopra indicate non sono poi tanti: quelli usati nel 99% dei casi sono "credere", "pensare", "sperare", "supporre" e similari.

I tuoi esempi:

> Penso sia necessario un chiarimento tra l’allenatore e la società.

Ok, il "che" dopo "penso" viene omesso.

> ... è una cosa che credo non farò mai più.

Qui è stato omesso il "che" dopo "credo".

> Il tempo ... è di circa 20 minuti che devo ammettere passano in fretta ...

Qui, secondo me, l'unica lettura possibile è:

> Il tempo ... è di circa 20 minuti che, devo ammettere, passano in fretta ...

quindi non c'è omissione di nessun "che". Devo comunque ammettere (eh) che non sono del tutto sicuro che "ammettere" non sia un verbo con cui si può omettere il "che".

> Ammetto che tu ti sia divertito -> Ammetto tu ti sia divertito (?)

La versione senza il "che" non mi suona benissimo, però neanche totalmente sbagliata. Propendo comunque per il "no".

In tutti i casi, nel tuo esempio il verbo della presunta subordinata sarebbe al presente indicativo ("passano"), quindi questa costruzione:

> Il tempo ... è di circa 20 minuti che devo ammettere che passano in fretta ...

non è "semplificabile" togliendo il secondo "che". Se si toglie, la frase cambia e va letta come

> Il tempo ... è di circa 20 minuti che, devo ammettere, passano in fretta ...

in cui "devo ammettere" passa al ruolo di inciso, perché se il verbo è al presente indicativo il "che" non si può togliere:

> Ammetto che il tempo passa in fretta -> *Ammetto il tempo passa in fretta

Per finire (e dopo averci pensato un po' di più), ci sono effettivamente rari casi in cui il "che" non congiunzione (ossia, pronome) si può omettere, anche se non sono del tutto sicuro di come la cosa sia classificabile dal punto di vista grammaticale. Sono casi in cui il "che", pur non essendo congiunzione, suona pleonastico, e gli unici esempi che mi vengono in mente sono del tipo:

> Che bel disegno che ha fatto Marco! -> Che bel disegno ha fatto Marco!
>
> Guarda che bel ragazzo che è diventato! -> Guarda che bel ragazzo è diventato!

Comment: Il *che* nelle oggettive si può omettere se il verbo segue immediatamente: *penso studierò domani* contro *penso che domani studierò*; ma il significato è diverso: nel primo caso stai rimandando, nel secondo stai progettando. Nell'esempio *guarda che bel ragazzo che è diventato* il secondo *che* è pleonastico, come in *che bello che è*.

Comment: Eccellente risposta, @karoshi, ma quello che a me non resta chiaro è quando è raccomandabile omettere la congiunzione "che".

Comment: @charo Purtroppo (o per fortuna) per quello non c'è molto da fare, è una questione di gusto, assonanza e "feeling" per la lingua, che si acquisisce solo con la pratica e l'ascolto. Sicuramente ci sono differenze d'uso anche tra gli stessi italiani. Un esempio col catalano: quando è raccomandabile dire "sota de la taula" e quando "sota la taula"? Suppongo che anche in questo caso valgano considerazioni analoghe, ossia non c'è una maniera "migliore" o "peggiore".

Comment: Capisco,  grazie!

Answer (score 3):

Come spiegato dall'[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/proposizioni-oggettive_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/):

> Nelle proposizioni subordinate oggettive, soprattutto di secondo grado, si
> può omettere la congiunzione che, per evitare l’accumulo di
> congiunzioni; i modi usati sono il congiuntivo o il condizionale

Infatti, dei tre esempi proposti, solo nel primo il "che" introdurrebbe una proposizione oggettiva, ed è pertanto omissibile, mentre nel secondo e nel terzo no, in quanto marca due proposizioni relative.

Comment: La prima frase ha una subordinata oggettiva, ma non è di secondo grado, e non c'è nessun accumulo di congiunzioni scrivendo "Penso che sia necessario ...". Non è così?

Comment: La seconda e la terza frasi invece avrebbero un accumulo di congiunzioni se non omettessero il "che".

Comment: @Charo è vero che l'omissione del "che" nelle proposizioni oggettive avviene *soprattutto* nel caso di subordinate di secondo grado, ma può verificarsi anche in altri contesti; sì, ma nella seconda e nella terza frase non si può omettere il "che", perchè non è una congiunzione, ma un pronome relativo :)

Comment: Nelle espressioni  "credo ***che*** non farò mai più", "devo ammettere ***che*** passano in fretta", penso che il vocabolo "che" sia una congiunzione. Credo che si tratti appunto di subordinate oggettive e che, d'accordo con la spiegazione della Crusca, in questi casi il "che" sia omesso per evitare un accumulo di "che".

Comment: Hai ragione nel fatto che l'altro "che" nella seconda e la terza frasi sono pronomi relativi e forse la spiegazione dovrebbe essere che la congiunzione "che" è stata omessa per evitare un accumulo di "che" nella stessa frase e non "per evitare l’accumulo di congiunzioni".